# Performing prime value pairs in python

Tags: python, primes

I am currently stuck on Project Euler problem 60.  The problem goes like this:

The primes 3, 7, 109, and 673, are quite remarkable. By taking any two primes and concatenating them in any order the result will always be prime. For example, taking 7 and 109, both 7109 and 1097 are prime. The sum of these four primes, 792, represents the lowest sum for a set of four primes with this property.

Find the lowest sum for a set of five primes for which any two primes concatenate to produce another prime.

In Python, I used and created the following functions.

```
def isprime(n):
    """Primality test using 6k+-1 optimization."""
    if n <= 3:
        return n > 1
    elif n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True

def prime_pair_sets(n):
    heap = [[3,7]]
    x = 11
    #Phase 1: Create a list of length n.
    while getMaxLength(heap)<n:
        if isprime(x):
            m = [x]
            for lst in heap:
                tmplst = [x]
                for p in lst:
                    if primePair(x,p):
                        tmplst.append(p)
                if len(tmplst)>len(m):
                    m=tmplst
            heap.append(m)
        x+=2
    s = sum(maxList(heap))
    #Phase 2: Find the lowest sum.
    for li in heap:
        y=x
        while s>(sum(li)+y) and len(li)<n:
            b = True
            for k in li:
                if not primePair(k,y):
                    b = False
            if b == True:
                li.append(y)
            y+=2
        if len(li)>=n:
            s = sum(li)
    return s

def getMaxLength(h):
    m = 0
    for s in h:
        if len(s) > m:
            m = len(s)
    return m

def primePair(x, y):
    return isprime(int(str(x)+str(y))) and isprime(int(str(y)+str(x)))

def maxList(h):
    result = []
    for s in h:
        if len(s)> len(result):
            result = s
    return result
```

I executed the primePairSets function using the first phase only.  After about an hour of waiting I got the sum of 74,617 (33647 + 23003 + 16451 + 1493 + 23). It turns out that it is not the sum we're looking for.  I tried the problem again using both phases.  After about two hours, I end up with the same wrong result.  Obviously, the answer is less than 74,617.  Can somebody help me find a more efficient way to solving this problem.  Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Use the sieve of Eratosthenes for prime checking, that will save you a lot of time.  If you have 3 elements in your partial list, then you need to check any new candidate against all 3 existing elements both as prefix and as postfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found**

- Primes: 13, 5197, 5701, 6733, 8389
- Sum: 26,033
- Run time reduced to ~10 seconds vs. 1-2 hours reported by OP solution.

**Approach**

- Backtracking algorithm based upon extending path containing list of primes
- A prime can be added to the path if its pairwise prime with all primes already in path
- Use Sieve of Eratosthenes to precompute primes up to max we expect to need
- For each prime, precompute which other primes it is pairwise prime with

**Code**

```
import functools
import time

# Decorator for function timing
def timer(func):
    """Print the runtime of the decorated function"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()    # 1
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()      # 2
        run_time = end_time - start_time    # 3
        print(f"Finished {func.__name__!r} in {run_time:.4f} secs")
        return value
    return wrapper_timer

#*************************************************************
# Prime number algorithms
#-------------------------------------------------------------
def _try_composite(a, d, n, s):
    if pow(a, d, n) == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(s):
        if pow(a, 2**i * d, n) == n-1:
            return False
    return True # n  is definitely composite
 
def is_prime(n, _precision_for_huge_n=16, _known_primes = set([2, 3, 5, 7])):
    if n in _known_primes:
        return True

    if n > 6 and not (n % 6) in (1, 5):
        # Check of form 6*q +/- 1
        return False

    if any((n % p) == 0 for p in _known_primes) or n in (0, 1):
        return False

    d, s = n - 1, 0
    while not d % 2:
        d, s = d >> 1, s + 1
    # Returns exact according to http://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html
    if n < 1373653: 
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3))
    if n < 25326001: 
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3, 5))
    if n < 118670087467: 
        if n == 3215031751: 
            return False
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3, 5, 7))
    if n < 2152302898747: 
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11))
    if n < 3474749660383: 
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13))
    if n < 341550071728321: 
        return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) for a in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17))
    # otherwise
    return not any(_try_composite(a, d, n, s) 
                   for a in _known_primes[:_precision_for_huge_n])

def primes235(limit):
    ' Prime generator using Sieve of Eratosthenes with factorization wheel of 2, 3, 5 '
    # Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python
    yield 2; yield 3; yield 5
    if limit < 7: return
    modPrms = [7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31]
    gaps = [4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6] # 2 loops for overflow
    ndxs = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7]
    lmtbf = (limit + 23) // 30 * 8 - 1 # integral number of wheels rounded up
    lmtsqrt = (int(limit ** 0.5) - 7)
    lmtsqrt = lmtsqrt // 30 * 8 + ndxs[lmtsqrt % 30] # round down on the wheel
    buf = [True] * (lmtbf + 1)
    for i in range(lmtsqrt + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            ci = i & 7; p = 30 * (i >> 3) + modPrms[ci]
            s = p * p - 7; p8 = p << 3
            for j in range(8):
                c = s // 30 * 8 + ndxs[s % 30]
                buf[c::p8] = [False] * ((lmtbf - c) // p8 + 1)
                s += p * gaps[ci]; ci += 1
    for i in range(lmtbf - 6 + (ndxs[(limit - 7) % 30])): # adjust for extras
        if buf[i]: yield (30 * (i >> 3) + modPrms[i & 7])
            
def prime_pair(x, y):
    ' Checks if two primes are prime pair (i.e. concatenation of two in either order is also a prime)'
    return is_prime(int(str(x)+str(y)))  and is_prime(int(str(y)+str(x)))


def find_pairs(primes):
    ' Creates dictionary of what primes can go with others as a pair'
    prime_pairs = {}
    for i, p in enumerate(primes):
        pairs = set()
        for j in range(i+1, len(primes)):
            if prime_pair(p, primes[j]):
                pairs.add(primes[j])
        prime_pairs[p] = pairs
    return prime_pairs

#*************************************************************
# Main functionality
#-------------------------------------------------------------   
@timer
def find_groups(max_prime = 9000, n = 5):
    '''
       Find group smallest sum of primes that are pairwise prime
       
       max_prime       - max prime to consider
       n                - the size of the group
    '''
    def fully_connected(p, path):
        '''
           checks if p is connected to all elements of the path 
           (i.e. group of primes)
        '''
        return all(p in prime_pairs.get(path_item, set()) for path_item in path)
    
    def backtracking(prime_pairs, n, path = None):
        if path is None:
            path = []
            
        if len(path) == n:
            yield path[:]
        else:
            if not path:
                for p, v in prime_pairs.items():
                    if v:
                        yield from backtracking(prime_pairs, n, path + [p])
            else:
                p = path[-1]
                for t in sorted(prime_pairs[p]):
                    if t > p and fully_connected(t, path):
                        yield from backtracking(prime_pairs, n, path + [t])
      
    primes = list(primes235(max_prime))     # Sieve for list of primes up to max_pair
    set_primes = set(primes)                # set of primes (for easy test if number is prime)
    prime_pairs = find_pairs(primes)        # Table of primes and set of other primes they can pair with
    
    return next(backtracking(prime_pairs, n), None)
```

**Test Runs**

```
for n, max_prime in [(2, 1000), (3, 1000), (4, 1000), (5, 9000)]:
    print(find_groups(max_prime = max_prime, n = n))
```

Run Times

```
n  max_prime    Primes Found                      Run Time (secs)
2  1000         (3, 7)                            0.1280
3  1000         (3, 37, 67)                       0.1240
4  1000         (3, 7, 109, 673)                  0.1233
5  40,000       (13, 5197, 5701, 6733, 8389)      7.1142
```

> Note: Timings above performed on an older Windows desktop computer,
> namely:
> ~7-year-old HP-Pavilion Desktop i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67 GHz

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code based on an  sieve of Eratosthenes which only stores the numbers 1 mod 6 and -1 mod 6. It is very fast.

```
def find_lowest_sum (pmax,num):
    n=int(str(pmax)+str(pmax))
    sieve5m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
    sieve1m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
    for i in range(1,int((n**0.5+1)/6)+1):
        if sieve5m6[i]:
            sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i-1]=[False]*(((n//6+1)-6*i*i-1)//(6*i-1)+1)
            sieve1m6[6*i*i-2*i::6*i-1]=[False]*(((n//6+1)-6*i*i+2*i-1)//(6*i-1)+1)
        if sieve1m6[i]:
            sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i+1]=[False]*(((n//6+1)-6*i*i-1)//(6*i+1)+1)
            sieve1m6[6*i*i+2*i::6*i+1]=[False]*(((n//6+1)-6*i*i-2*i-1)//(6*i+1)+1)

    
    def test_concatenate (p1,p2):
        ck=0
        p3=int(str(p1)+str(p2)) 
        if  sieve1m6[(p3-1)//6] and p3%6==1:
            ck=1
        elif  sieve5m6[(p3+1)//6]and p3%6==5:
            ck=1 
        if ck==1:
            p3=int(str(p2)+str(p1))
            if  sieve1m6[(p3-1)//6] and p3%6==1:
                ck=2
            elif  sieve5m6[(p3+1)//6]and p3%6==5:
                ck=2 
        if ck==2:
             return True
        else: 
             return False

    kmax=(pmax+1)//6
    s1=5*pmax
    P1=[]
    P2=[]
    p=3
    kmin=0
    while p<s1//5:
        if p==3 or(p%6==1 and sieve1m6[(p-1)//6])or(p%6==5 and sieve5m6[(p+1)//6]):
            P=[]
            if p%6==1:
                kmin=p//6
            elif p%6==5:
                kmin=(p+1)//6
                if  sieve1m6[kmin]:
                    if test_concatenate(p,6*kmin+1):
                        P.append(6*kmin+1) 

            for  k in range(kmin+1,kmax):
                if  sieve5m6[k]:
                    if test_concatenate(p,6*k-1):
                        P.append(6*k-1) 
                if  sieve1m6[k]:
                    if test_concatenate(p,6*k+1):
                        P.append(6*k+1) 

            i1=0
            while i1<len(P) and P[i1]<s1:
                P1=[p]
                s=p
                P1.append(P[i1])
                s+=P[i1]

                for i2 in range(i1+1,len(P)):
                    for i3 in range(1,len(P1)):
                        ck=test_concatenate(P[i2],P1[i3])
                        if  ck==False:
                            break
                    if len(P1)-1==i3 and ck==True:
                        P1.append(P[i2])
                        s+=P[i2]
                    if len(P1)==num:
                        if s<s1:
                            P2=P1
                            s1=s
                        break
 
                i1+=1
        p+=2
    return P2



P=find_lowest_sum(9001,5)


print(P)
s=0
for i in range(0,len(P)):
    s+=P[i]
print(s)
```